# Get "usable" screen area in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, view, scrollview, visible

Actually I have a screen that the root is a a `ScrollableView`, but when the user enters for the first time I have to show a "tooltip". The problem is that I have to show an image "anchored" to the bottom of the view with a gradient int the background.

So here is the problem. I need to know where to put this view, because it will depend on the size of the screen.

[image]

To achieve this I have the view as:

**xml file**

```
<ScrollView>
    <ConstraintLayout>
        ....

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/first_open_tooltip"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_white_transp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/mini_marker"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="100dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_bg_tooltip_marker"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/discover_new_tooltip"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/bg_tooltip"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/mini_marker"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="224dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:text="@string/firstopen_tooltip"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tooltip"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/tooltip"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tooltip" />

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

With that, in the Fragment I verify if is the first time of the user.

If it is, then I change the LayoutParams of the FrameLayout to make it fit on the screen:

```
val display = activity!!.windowManager.defaultDisplay
val size = Point()
display.getSize(size)
val height = size.y

var lp = discover_first_open_tooltip.layoutParams
lp.height = height //<--problem
first_open_tooltip.layoutParams = lp
```

**Problem**

So here is where I have the problem, because I'm getting the full screen height, and then the tooltip hides because in the bottom.

Is there any way to just get the "Visible Area" (in the image)?

Comment: Have you tried `DisplayMetrics` and then substracting the status bar, navigation bar, and your bottom navigation views' heights?

Comment: Is there any way to get the size of this views? Or usually are same size, for example... 48dp? because If I'm not wrong, I have transform to dp -> px to set the layout params,no?

Comment: You don't need to guess the size (48dp most of the time) of those views. Just run the calculations I pointed to at runtime. And yes you'll need them in PX.

Answer (score 1):

From you sketch it looks like the tooltip is not situated on the scroll plane, but a top of the bottom action bar. Therefore I propose a layout structured like this:

```
<ScrollView>
    <ConstraintLayout>
        ....
    </ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
<ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <PutYourToolTipHere        
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <YourMenuBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</ConstraintLayout>
```

The point of it is to overlay the tooltip instead of showing it in the scrollview.